# A question about namespace in Tcl

Tags: namespaces, export, tcl

I have two question about namespace in Tcl.

```
namespace eval ::dai {
         set a 5
         set b 10
         namespace export *
}
```

My questions are:

1. `export *` - the export will make some variable inside this namespace can be used in other namespace, but what does this `export *` mean?
2. Set a 5, should not we use `variable a 5`? are they the same? some tutorials say inside namespace, we should use `variable`, what is the difference between `variable` and `set` in namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) As is (supposed to be) logical for Unix users, "*" means "everything available at the moment".  It's like when you do `rm -f *` in a shell, the shell expands "*" and replaces it with a list of all the files present in the current directory.  Actually, as [`namespace` manual states](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M12) you can specify more elaborate patters than simple "*". To learn what that "glob-style" thing mentioned there means read about [`string match`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40).

2) The question "should not we use..." is incorrect because it depends on what you want to do.  If you want to declare a variable located in the namespace, use `variable`.  If you want to set a variable, use `set`, but bevare that if that variable `x` is not exist in the namespace yet, Tcl will attempt to find a global variablte with this name, see:

```
% set x 5
5
% namespace eval foo {
    set x 10
  }
10
% set x
10
# ^^ observe that the global variable has been assigned
% namespace eval foo {
    variable x
    set x 20
  }
20
% set x
10
# ^^ observe that now `set x 20` found the variable `x` in the namespace and assigned to it
```

This is explained in the ["NAME RESOLUTION" section of the `namespace` man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M26).

Note that this behaviour may appear illogical, but it actually matches that of the procedure scope: if you do `set foo bar` in a procedure body, this means setting the *local* variable unless you stated otherwise using either `global` or `variable` or by using a fully-qualified name (like `::ns::foo`).

Comment: _Always_ **declare** _variables in namespaces_ with `variable`. Failure to do so will cause much confusion if you happen to have a global variable with the same name. Once declared, you may do anything you want with it. However, `namespace export` (and `namespace import`) only ever works with commands; the equivalent for variables is to use a fully-qualified variable name with `variable`, `upvar` or `namespace upvar`.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it doesn't seem to actually match the procedure scope. In a proc,`set x 10` will set the local var unless previously specified as non local, where as in a namespace eval `set x 10` will set the global var unless previously specified as non global?

Comment: @copper.hat, No, *unless* you have a global variable "x". See for yourself: run `tclsh` (or `tkcon`) and then execute there: `set ::x 10; namespace eval foo { set x 42; set y 24 }`. Now try: `info vars ::*` and `info vars ::foo::*`. And now try `set ::x`. You'll see that the namespace "foo" only contains a single variable `y` and the first `set` command in the namespace context modified the global "x" because it already existed (while "y" was not).

Comment: @copper.hat, to rephrase: the `set` command run in a namespace context with a name of a variable not containing "::" will work as follows: 1) if there exists a namespaced variable (declared earlier with the `variable` command), it is used; otherwise 2) if there's a global variable with the matching name, it is used; otherwise 3) a variable with that name is created in the namespace, and used.  These rules are explained in the manual page of the `namespace` command.

Comment: @kostix: Thanks for the reply! I am still confused (this is about the 'but it actually matches...' part of the last sentence of your answer). I follow the namespace 'scoping' but it seems different from proc in that inside a proc, set x 42 will create a local var if not already declared global (unlike the order 2),3)) in your previous comment?

Comment: @copper.hat, ah, I see. I think what I had in mind writing that "... matches ..." bit is different from what you put into it, and so I'd better not have written that at all :-) I tried to highlight that the context matters: the behaviour of the `set` command in either case depends on specific prior commands having been executed.

Comment: @copper.hat, Note that technically in stock Tcl interpreter (I mean, "official" -- other implementations are free to use different approaches) each *scope* (procedure, namespace, interp-global) has a "variable table", and that's what gets manipulated by commands such as `variable` and `global`. Any variable lookup first hits this table in the current scope; rules for looking up further scopes differ between procs and namespaces (I think this might have something to do with backwards-compatibility and "the least WTF principle" as Tcl not always had namespaces).

Comment: @copper.hat, Like, say, executing `global` in a proc inserts an entry in the proc's variable table which "links" to the global variable. Then all the references to the matching local name will get resolved to that global variable. I think I was thinking about these tables when I was writing that sentence we're discussing. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 2):

`namespace export` only applies to commands (i.e. `proc`s) in the namespace: it registers them as being eligible to be imported into another namespace.  For example:

```
% package require textutil
0.7.1
% textutil::splitx abcdefghij {[aeiou]}
{} bcd fgh j
% splitx abcdefghij {[aeiou]}
invalid command name "splitx"
while evaluating {splitx abcdefghij {[aeiou]}}
% namespace import textutil::*
% splitx abcdefghij {[aeiou]}
{} bcd fgh j
```